# How to close a particular Xcode Project from terminal

Tags: terminal, xcode7, exit

I have tried using pkill Xcode to quit Xcode, but that quits all the Xcode projects that are open. I would like to close only a particular project in Xcode from terminal. Is there any way I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in terminal.

> KillAll Xcode

This will close all Xcode processes.